# where in any islamic scripture it is written that all khalifa should be from quraysh?

Tags: fiqh, hadith-interpretation

Where in any islamic scripture it is written that all khalifa should be from quraysh  ?

Comment: In his tarikh al-Khulafa' imam as-Suyuti discussed in a whole chapter the ahadith saying that the Khilafa should be from Quraysh.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Authority of ruling will remain with Quraish, even if only two of them remained." ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/11))
>
> The Caliphate will remain among the Quraish even if only two persons are left (on the earth), ([Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/4))

If we call anyone else Khalifa we would be saying the opposite of what the Prophet (SAW) said: "Caliphate does not have to remain with the Quraysh" when the Prophet (SAW) said it **will**. We would basically be, NaOzobiAllah, calling him a liar when he cannot be a liar, so we would have to call the person claiming a non-Quraishi is a Khalifah a liar instead.

So, since no one can truthfully claim a non-Quraishi is a Khalifah, they cannot be a rightful Khalifah.

Comment: Have you looked at scholarly commentaries on this Hadith? Many scholars reject what otherwise is deemed as saheeh because it goes against basic reason. For example: The Caliphate did not remain only with Quraish, this is a basic historical fact. The Hadith was not restrained to only guided caliphs, and even then, Umar Ibn abdelaziz was not a Quraishi and he is considered by many to be one of them, etc.

Comment: wasn’t he born in Medina?

Comment: who says you can take it back through lineage? Ismael was not from Mecca, are you going to say the Prophet PBUH was not Meccan?

Comment: That’s fine. But the Caliphate did not remain only with the Quraish. This is a fact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75311/discussion-between-the-z-and-shadi).

Comment: What is "verse number" of this quoted text in the scripture and any url online?

Comment: @zaxebo1 . It is a hadith, it doesn't have a verse number. But, I added links to a website.

Comment: @Shadi [Omar ibn Abdalaziz -Arabic Wikipedia-](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B2) was born in Medina yes but his lineage is clearly Qurashi